# Is wiki.ros.org down?

Tags: ros, offline, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is anybody else experciencing the ROS wiki to be unreachable as well? I haven't been able to reach it in the last 4 and a half hours...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130386/is-wiki.ros.org-down?/) by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 432 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best page to see the status of the ROS webservices is http://status.ros.org.

The wiki is up again by now.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-02-18**:
Oh, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it's down (you can [check on the Internet](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/wiki.ros.org.html)). [ros.org](http://ros.org) as well actually. This was reported on the [mailing list](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/ros-org-down-td4020670.html). We just need to wait for it to be fixed.

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-02-18**:
Also, up-to-date mirror could be reached here:
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/ :)